# Selenium Python: Can't Get Path To Chat Element On Google Hangouts

Tags: python, css, selenium

I've been having a lot of trouble with the selenium module in python recently. I am trying to make a script that can automate sending messages to my friends as requested by one of them.

I am able to log into Google Hangouts with it, but I am having considerable difficulty in accessing the chats. If I want to click on a conversation to open the chat window, I would think that I could just select the id with selenium's find_element_by_id() function.

However, this does not work as Hangouts uses dynamic ids which change after certain events. I don't really know what to do. I tried using the xpath but that doesn't work either. I don't really know what do at this point as nothing I'm trying seems to work.

If you want to reproduce this for yourself, you are going to have to get chromedriver and input the path. You are also going to have to put in your own email and password into the the correct send_keys() functions.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

# get browser set up
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,
                           executable_path=r"chromedriver path")
browser.get('https://stackoverflow.com/users/login')

# locate and click sign in button on stackoverflow (can't sign in on regular google)
google_button = browser.find_element_by_class_name('s-btn__google')
google_button.click()
email_elem = browser.find_element_by_id('identifierId')
email_elem.send_keys('email')
next_button = browser.find_element_by_id('identifierNext')
next_button.click()
# enters password 
while True:
    try:
        pwd_elem = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('input[type = "password"]')
        pwd_elem.send_keys('password')
        break
    except:
        time.sleep(1)
next_button = browser.find_element_by_id("passwordNext")
next_button.click()
while True:
    try:
    # gets to hangouts
        browser.execute_script('''window.open("https://hangouts.google.com/", "_blank");''')
        browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[-1])
        break
    except:
        time.sleep(1)
refreshed = False
while True:
    try:
        # CAN'T FIND PATH TO CHAT
        chat = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]')
        chat.click()
        break
    except:
        print('not found')
        if not refreshed:
        # refreshes because hangouts will first load without signing in
            browser.refresh()
            refreshed = True
        time.sleep(4)
```

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: In the code I've put a comment in caps saying that I can't find the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your element inside a frame, you need switch first:

```
browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_class_name('Xyqxtc'))

chat = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]')
chat.click()
```

But absolute path is not recommended, it is vulnerable to change.

The following locator looks better:

```
chat = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('div.MM')
```